# GitHub repository not listing in Google search

Tags: github, listings

I created my first repository with GitHub but when I try to google it, its not listing
[RoboSpice-Extn-Retrofit-Tutorial](https://github.com/amityadav1984/RoboSpice-Extn-Retrofit-Tutorial)

**EDIT**

I don't know how long it will take. On the other hand anyone can take a help of [Google Webmaster](http://www.google.com/addurl.html), this would solve your problem in minutes :)

Comment: can you please tell me how did you add your repository to google search engine and verified it?

Comment: @MrJSingh I didn't add repository to search engine manually

Comment: But you mentioned that you used Web master tools?

Comment: Yes , we should also use Webmaster. Are you finding any difficulty on using it?

Comment: Yes when I add github repo to Web master then it want to verify and there I'm stuck.

Comment: @MrJSingh As I remembered after adding to Webmaster my one is start listing

Comment: Ok i don't know what's changed since that but it clearly asking for validation and it's unable to validate my repo there. I guess I need to dig more deep in webmaster 

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is actually a SEO question which is off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That repo seems to have been created less than an hour ago.
Give Google a little time to parse the new repos, and it should show up.

Note that it is referenced by GitHub search already:

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=RoboSpice-Extn-Retrofit-Tutorial

As the OP used the [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url) to submit its url, the [repo is now indexed in Google](https://www.google.fr/search?q=RoboSpice-Extn-Retrofit-Tutorial).

---

Update 2019: the section "[Enabling GitHub Pages to publish your site from master or gh-pages](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages#enabling-github-pages-to-publish-your-site-from-master-or-gh-pages)" is now (since 2014) more precise:

> To select `master` or `gh-pages` as your publishing source, you must have the branch present in your repository.
>   If you don't have a `master` or `gh-pages` branch, you can create them and then return to source settings to change your publishing source.

Once the correct branch is created/populated, and selected as the publishing source, the Google indexing seems to be very quick.

Comment: Thanks but what about `github.io` pages? My post months before cannot be get from google.

Comment: @SummerSun It should be indexed unless you are using a domain of your own with a robots.txt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32805279/6309

Comment: I created Repository "ArmoredDeathmatch" 4 years ago. I am not able to find it using google search. Only search box on github.com can find it.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the indexing of Google, Bing, DuckDuckGo for a GitHub page?

Comment: @Royi I answered in 2015 about robot.txt (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32805279/6309), but the other answer about meta directive (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56223855/6309) is more up-to-date.

Comment: In my case, after 3 months nothing shows up on google.

Comment: @DimiDak What is your [publication source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)? You might get more from an independent question here, with a reference back to this answer, and detailing your current setup.

Comment: @VonC , I followed the guide about GitHub Pages in your comment just now. I'll come back later, thanx.

Answer (score 19):

This is how I managed to get at least my github pages-page to be found on Google:

1. go to google search console https://search.google.com/search-console/
2. add new "property" with "URL prefix" as suggested
3. add the meta tag on your github-pages site (html-head) as described, looks like `<meta name="google-site-verification" content="...">`
4. paste your page URL to the "search bar" on the top of the search console and press `<Enter>`. **Important:** use full path to page, **including the .html page**, e.g. `https://<user>.github.io/<your repo>/demo/index.html`
5. Click on "request indexing"

I first only did points 1-3 with the URL `https://<user>.github.io/<my-repo>/demo/` and the page still did not show up after waiting for a month. However after doing points (4) and (5) my github-pages site immediately showed up in the Google search results.

edit: one day later also the github repository showed up on Google search (but maybe only because I link the original repository in my github-pages site).

Comment: Which URL are you using in Step 2?  In Step 2 are you using the URL for your `GitHub Page` or the URL for the `gh-pages` `branch` of your `GitHub repository` or the URL shown in your Step 4 or the URL that appears when you first access your `GitHub repository` (without `/tree/gh-pages` or `/tree/main` at the end)?  I can find no search bar at the top of `Google Search Console` mentioned in Step 4.  I can find no way to request indexing mentioned in Step 5.  I see a `Verify` button.  But when I click that button I get a message that the `meta tag is incorrect`.

Comment: As stated in my answer: use the URL of your Github Page like `https://<user>.github.io/<my-repo>/demo/` for steps 1-3. The search bar on the top looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/iZQd6qP.png

Comment: The search bar mentioned in Step 4 only appears if site verification is successful in Step 3.  That search bar is not visible prior to Step 4.  The URL shown in Step 4 is very confusing because it is combining the URL for the GitHub Page with the index.html file from the GitHub repository.  When I press Enter in Step 4 I get a message that "Something went wrong" no matter what URL I paste into the search bar.  Perhaps I need to wait a day or more before I can complete Step 4.  You mentioned that a month passed before you completed Step 4.

Comment: On Github Page you have the same files as in your GitHub repository (gh-pages branch or also main/master, depending on configuration), but hosted on a webserver, so I don't think it's confusing. The url `https://<user>.github.io/<your repo>/demo/index.html` is just an example, if you don't have `index.html` or folder `demo` in your repo (gh-pages, master/main) branch, it won't work, you have to use a file existing in your repo.

Comment: After posting my last comment I discovered that the `GitHub Page` can be displayed with or without `index.html` at the end of its `URL`. I still got an error in Step 4 when I pressed Enter.  I had to wait ~48 hours before I could complete Step 4.  Then I requested indexing as in Step 5.  I got a message that the `URL` is not on `Google`.  Maybe I need to wait another day or two for Google to index the site to complete Step 5.

Answer (score 5):

When GitHub auto-generate your page, you get only the `_config.yml` file and not the html files. So if you want to keep the default page and not write html yourself, you have to:

- Find the original template from the theme's repository, for the slate theme the template is https://github.com/pages-themes/slate/blob/master/_layouts/default.html
- Create a folder named `_layout`
- Create a file called `_layouts/default.html`
- In the `default.html` copy and paste the contents of the template
- Follow klues post and generate your `<meta name="google-site-verification" content="...">` tag
- Add the meta tag to `default.html`

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you give some time to Google it will reflect in google search
Make sure to use better key words in your github ReadMe and title,tags of repo to make it more visible
See this for an Example:
https://github.com/anupama513/Tk102-gps-data-parser-nodejs-server