# Why my github repo cannot be searched in google?

Tags: github

I have selected my repo as master branch in github.
I have added the request in google search console.
It has been two weeks, I still cannot search my repo in google.
https://github.com/hcleung35/SRGAN_Cramer
Any one can help?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub repository not listing in Google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199705/github-repository-not-listing-in-google-search)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the two popular methods mentioned in that site, but not working.

Comment: anyone help? thanks