# My GitHub repositories are not known by Google

Tags: github

I created my repository with GitHub.

When I try to google it, its not listing in the search.

https://github.com/Subathra19/An-innovative-packet-labelling-scheme-TCP-PLATO-for-Data-Center-Networks

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you explain your issue

Answer (score 0):

If this page was created newly, it might not show up in the google search result immediately because google has not indexed the page yet.
Apart from this, there are multiple other factors which might be the reason your page is not showing up in the google.

Read here for more details: [GitHub repository not listing in Google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199705/github-repository-not-listing-in-google-search)